# Powerapp - onstart date function returning wrong date for Mondays

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula

I am trying to set a weeklist variable in the onstart of the app in powerapp with the below code.

```
Concurrent(
    Set(
        currentUser,
        User()
    ),
    Set(
        currentMonday,
        DateAdd(
            Today(),
            -1 * (Weekday(
                Today(),
                StartOfWeek.Monday
            ) - 1),
            TimeUnit.Days
        )
    ),
    Set(
        weeksList,
        ForAll(
            Sequence(
                20,
                Day(
                    DateAdd(
            Today(),
            -1 * (Weekday(
                Today(),
                StartOfWeek.Monday
            ) - 1),
            TimeUnit.Days
            )
                ) - 28,
                7
            ),
             Date(
                Year(Today()),
                Month(Today()),
                Value
            )
        )
    )
);
```

The last `Set` above is returning wrong date for Monday. For example, instead of 7/31/2023 it is returning 08/03/2023 as monday and set the next 20 values according to 8/3. This was working till last week, but looks the formula is not fool proof for any given day/date.

Please help.

When I tried to use the CurrentMonday set variable and add 6 days, it is coming correctly, but I need 20 weeks values to show in drop down which is not working. The date calculation that has -28 after finding the current monday date value looks to be wrong, but unable to crack it. Please share any inputs, which would be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your list to have 20 Mondays, starting 4 Mondays before the current one, you can use this expression:

```
Set(
  currentMonday,
  DateAdd(Today(), -1 * (Weekday( t, StartOfWeek.Monday ) - 1), TimeUnit.Days));
Set(
  weeksList,
  ForAll(
    Sequence(20, -28, 7), // 20 elements, starting from -28, incremented by 7
    DateAdd(currentMonday, Value, TimeUnit.Days)
  )
)
```

Notice that you don't need to use the Concurrent function in this scenario - the calculations for the dates are really fast, and you won't benefit from concurrency with this. This is more useful when there are multiple calls that may go over the network (and in your case there is only one, the call to `User()`).